# Mathematica table error messages

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, message

For the following (some package-related statements omitted):

```
CartesianMap[ func_, {x0_,x1_,dx_}, {y0_,y1_,dy_} ] = 
  Module[ { x, y, tx, ty, llpx, llpy},
    tx = Table[{Re[func[x + I y]], Im[func[x + I y]]}, 
                  {x, x0, x1, dx}, {y, y0, y1, dy}]; 
    ty = Table[{Re[func[x + I y]], Im[func[x + I y]]}, 
                  {y, y0, y1, dy}, {x, x0, x1, dx}];
    llpx = ListLinePlot[tx];
    llpy = ListLinePlot[ty];
    Show[ llpx, llpy, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                 ImageSize -> Large]
  ]

CartesianMap[ Cos, { 0.2, Pi - 0.2, (Pi - 0.4)/19}, {-2, 2, 4/16}]
```

When I execute:

```
In[99]:= << CartesianMap1.m
```

I get the following errors:

```
During evaluation of In[99]:= Table::iterb: Iterator {x$31836,x0,x1,dx} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

During evaluation of In[99]:= Table::iterb: Iterator {y$31836,y0,y1,dy} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

During evaluation of In[99]:= ListLinePlot::lpn: Table[{Re[func[x$31836+I y$31836]],Im[func[x$31836+I y$31836]]},{x$31836,x0,x1,dx},{y$31836,y0,y1,dy}] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. >>

During evaluation of In[99]:= ListLinePlot::lpn: Table[{Re[func[x$31836+I y$31836]],Im[func[x$31836+I y$31836]]},{y$31836,y0,y1,dy},{x$31836,x0,x1,dx}] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. >>

During evaluation of In[99]:= Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[ListLinePlot[Table[{Re[func[x$31836+Times[<<2>>]]],Im[func[x$31836+Times[<<2>>]]]},{x$31836,x0,x1,dx},{y$31836,y0,y1,dy}]],ListLinePlot[Table[{Re[func[x$31836+Times[<<2>>]]],Im[func[x$31836+Times[<<2>>]]]},{y$31836,y0,y1,dy},{x$31836,x0,x1,dx}]],Axes->True,AspectRatio->Automatic,ImageSize->Large]. >>

**************************************************************
End error messages.
```

1. The generated graphics are good.
2. The problem is that at compile time the iterators for table are arguments, so not defined.  The check should be at run time, not compile time. Poor decision by Wolfram.
3. Prefixing all statements with Quiet[...] is ugly.
4. Is there a clean solution to the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions should be defined with [SetDelayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`), i.e.

```
CartesianMap[func_, {x0_, x1_, dx_}, {y0_, y1_, dy_}] :=
  Module[{x, y, tx, ty, llpx, llpy},
  tx = ...
```